# Python Requests: Invalid Header Name

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send a request with the header: ":hello". However, the leading colon causes the script to not function properly, and emit this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

(first few lines removed for my privacy)

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 109, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 353, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1057, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1096, in _send_request
    self.putheader(hdr, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1030, in putheader
    raise ValueError('Invalid header name %r' % (header,))
ValueError: Invalid header name ':hello'
```

Is there a workaround for this? My script is:

```
import requests
headers = {'user-agent': 'alsotesting', ':hello': 'test'}
requests.post("my server", headers=headers)
```

Comment: Well the error message says it all: `:header` is not a valid HTTP header name. It must not start with a `:`.

Comment: But it needs to start with a colon to use the protocol. There are several known instances of browsers having the capability to send these requests. For example: instagram.com uses ":authority" headers.

Comment: @Rob can you give an example of what you mean, maybe with a reference? I think you might be confused.

Comment: For example, instagram has a ":authority" header. Here is a picture: http://puu.sh/m1iu4/0e7a71362a.png

Comment: A header starting with a colon violated the HTTP protocol. It is part of the seperators and seperators must not be part of the header name. (see RFC 2616 section 2.2 and 4.2 for details). So, `httplib` is right to reject the header.

Comment: I realize this, but there is a colon in the name of some headers, and how are they not being prevented?

Comment: Adhering to the HTTP protocol more strictly than any browser (after all, all major browsers work with instagram) is not realistic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As your error says, `:header` is not a valid HTTP header name (you cannot start headers with ":" - see [documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2)). You should change

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'alsotesting', ':hello': 'test'}
```

to

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'alsotesting', 'hello': 'test'}
```

Edit: HTTP/2 uses pseudo-headers fields, which start with a colon (see [documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.1)). Also, as explained [here](https://aprescott.com/posts/spdy-colon-headers), you may see some headers starting with a colon in Chrome's Developer Tools, which can happen when Chrome is talking to a web server using SPDY - and also HTTP/2 (which is based on SPDY/2), which correspond to pseudo-headers. As stated in documentation, **pseudo-header fields are not HTTP header fields**.

In conclusion, header fields starting with a colon are not allowed with standard HTTP protocol, so that is why you are getting the `Invalid header name` error

Comment: I realize this, but there is a colon in the name of some headers (for example, instagram), so how are they not being prevented? puu.sh/m1iu4/0e7a71362a.png

Comment: I believe that is using SPDY protocol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) or any other protocol different from HTTP. HTTP headers do not allow that format

Comment: It says in the x-requested-with header that it's HTTP, though. http://puu.sh/m1l3z/6dc2a38132.png

Comment: It's taken from the chrome networking console which _only_ captures http requests, to my knowledge

Comment: Could you post the whole request and response?

Comment: As explained here (https://aprescott.com/posts/spdy-colon-headers),  when Chrome is talking to a web server using SPDY, if you check the HTTP request headers in Developer Tools, you’ll find some non-standard-looking headers that all start with colons.

Comment: The website from your request, (https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/574891263/unfollow/) supports HTTP/2. As show here (https://http2.github.io/faq/#whats-the-relationship-with-spdy), SPDY/2 is the basis for HTTP/2. You can check if the website your at supports HTTP/2 or SPDY with this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http2-and-spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin/related

Comment: As I said, and you can verify here (https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test), instagram supports HTTP/2, which is based on SPDY/2.

Comment: those colons at the beginning you are seeing are from pseudo-headers fields, as you can see in documentation: (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.1)

Comment: pseudo-header fields are NOT HTTP header fields (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.1)