# Python ValueError: Invalid header name b':authority

Tags: python, python-3.x, header, python-requests, pyspider

I see the ':' is error, but I can't find  a way to solve it.

```
ValueError: Invalid header name b':authority'
```

It's the error:

```
File "tmall.py", line 23, in get_url
response = sessions.get(url=url,headers =headers)

File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 501, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)

File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 609, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
timeout=timeout

File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)

File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 356, in _make_request
conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)

File "E:\python\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

File "E:\python\lib\http\client.py", line 1280, in _send_request
self.putheader(hdr, value)

File "E:\python\lib\http\client.py", line 1207, in putheader
raise ValueError('Invalid header name %r' % (header,))
```

---

It's the code:

```
import requests
headers = {
    ':authority':'list.tmall.com',
    ':method':'GET',
    ':path':path}
sessions = requests.session();
response = sessions.get(url=url,headers =headers)
```

Comment: Just remove the ":" from the keys in your headers

Comment: @Acepcs But the headers doesn't has“：” ，it can't requests and get the right web.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to understand what you're saying. It looks like you need to change `':authority'` to `'authority'` for each header

Comment: @PeterGibson Thanks

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34372413/12242023 solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import httplib

httplib._is_legal_header_name = re.compile(r':|\A[^:\s][^:\r\n]*\Z').match
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please edit your answer and elaborate on that.

Comment: Rewrite the regular expression of httplib. _is_legal_header_name

sorry，

Comment: For Python 3.7, it's     
`import http.client`
`http.client._is_legal_header_name = re.compile(rb'[^\s][^:\r\n]*').fullmatch`

Comment: i get `Invalid header value b'token ghp<ghtoken>\n'` when calling `Github(token).get_user()`. I have `lf` as `line ending` of the token file. What is `b` at the begin?